Uniqueness of optimal solution to infinite dimensional linear program
I am interested in the uniqueness of the solution to a linear program. This seems to be well-understood in the finite dimensional Euclidean setting. However, I am interested in potentially infinite dimensional settings, where I struggle to find relevant results in the literature.
I am particularly interested in the following linear program:
$$\max_{x} \int_{\Omega} x(\omega) d\mu(\omega), \text{ subject to } \int_{\Omega} x(\omega) d\nu(\omega) \leq 1, \forall \nu \in N \text{, and } x(\omega) \geq 0,$$
where $\mu$ is a probability measure and $N$ an arbitrary convex collection of probability measures, both on some measurable space $\Omega$.
I had hoped to find some well-known infinite-dimensional linear programming theorem that characterizes the uniqueness, but I was surprised how hard it was to find results on this topic.
Does anyone know a good starting point of where to look?

@EricTowers I was also thinking about infinitely many linear constraints.
Would that be captured by an arbitrary convex constraint? So that it would be a linear objective over a convex constraint?

@EricTowers I am specifically interested in possibly infinite dimensional cases, with infinitely many constraints. For example, in some inner product space I could define
$\max_x c'x$,
subject to:
$a'x \leq 1$ for every $a \in A$,
$x \geq 0$.
where A is some arbitrary subset of the inner product space.
In the finite dimensional setting I believe it is sufficient that $c \not\in A$. But I highly doubt that would be enough in the infinite dimensional setting.

Thanks, I have completely rewritten my question to make it more clear and to-the-point.
